# c言語コンパイラについてgccとclang

Tags: c

有名なコンパイラとして、gccとclangが存在しますが、webの記事を参照するとclangでビルドされたバイナリの方が性能が良いというような内容が多く見られます。
これは、現代的にはc言語のソースをビルドし、品質(省メモリ、実行速度)の良いバイナリを生成するのが目的ならば、すでにllvm環境のほうが有利でしかない状況になっているのが現状であるという認識で正しいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x86 や x86-64 に限定してならば Yes と言っていいんぢゃないかな。でもだからといって全てのプログラマが gcc を捨てて clang に移行できるかというとそんなこともなくて。

世の中にはそれ以外の CPU がいっぱいあって gcc はそれらの多くに（普通のプログラマでは名前を聞いたことないようなマイナーな CPU にも）対応しているのに対して clang がサポートしている CPU は少ないとかの差はあるっすね。

x86/64 だと intel c++ compiler ってのもあるけどウチでは使っていないし、今 2018 年の時点でのコード効率比較記事ってのはちょっと探しただけでは見つからなかった。

（で、どうしても [c](/questions/tagged/c)/[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) でなきゃならないんだったら別だけど、できるだけ [c](/questions/tagged/c)/[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) を避けるってのが現代の世の趨勢）

Comment: なぜ、c/c++は避けられているのでしょうか？

Comment: C は超絶古い言語なのでその分ユーザーが多いんだけど、プログラマが十分有能なことを前提にしてて、その分バグらせやすいです。最近の言語はその辺を反面教師にしていて、プログラマが不慣れでもバグを入れにくいシステムを用意している。実行時性能より開発期間の短縮を狙うには C は不向きっすね。で、今どきのマシンは十分高速なので、ならば開発期間が短いほうが儲かるってこと。 C++ もその辺の状況は同じってことで。

Comment: 製品の品質に優れたバイナリを生成し消費者に貢献することよりも、リリースサイクルが高速であるほうが儲かる理由はなんなのでしょうか？

Comment: スマホゲームとか見てたらわかるんぢゃない？　新イベントリリース（＝新バージョンプログラム提供）は事前に予告されていて、間に合わなかったら詫び石っす（予定時刻までにバグが取り切れなかったら詫び石ってことで）

Comment: なるほど、スマホゲームについてであればそもそも消費者がソフトウェアやネットワークを利用して経済的な効用を得るという意識がないか、もしくはすでに満たされており、文化圏に需要がはみ出していて、その層をターゲットにした開発においては品質より約束の通りの日程にリリースがされることが目的であると、言うことでしょうか。

Comment: 品質をおろそかにして良いわけがないけど、例えば C でプログラム書いて実行時間が３秒のソフトがリリースまで３日要したってのと、他の言語で書いて実行時間が１０秒のソフトが１日でリリースできました、だと一般的には後者のほうが喜ばれると思うよ。お客様的には２日別の仕事ができるわけだし。

Comment: そうですか、つまり”お客様”とは消費者ではなく、元請けに近い関係の会社のことである。ということですね。

Comment: まあ、開発者ですから、お客様はその開発の依頼主とか依頼元になりますよね。それに開発者も、開発期間が1/3なら、3件近い案件を受けてその分利益を出せます。また、あとでバグが見つかった時の工数は持ち出しだったり、今の案件を遅延させるので開発者にもマイナスだと思います

Comment: まあWebGLとかUnityの影響でゲーム業界がC++離れしているのは確かですが、一方で今ホットなFinTechだったり機械学習だったりとC++がどんどん使われている分野もあるので、向き不向きの問題かなと

Answer (score 10):

> 現代的にはc言語のソースをビルドし、品質(省メモリ、実行速度)の良いバイナリを生成するのが目的ならば、すでにllvm環境のほうが有利でしかない状況になっているのが現状であるという認識で正しいでしょうか？

絶対的な答えのない質問の一種ですが、おそらく正確な認識ではありません。GCC、LLVM/Clang両コンパイラともに恒常的なバージョンアップが行われており、「どちらが高性能か」という短絡的な結論付けは乱暴と思います。

事実として言えるのは、後発プロダクトであるLLVM/ClangがGCCと並ぶまでに進化し、競争原理による性能改善や利便性能向上をもたらし、一般開発者にとってはメリットがあるという点です。

---

コンパイラの「性能」を、一つの側面のみから評価することは大変危険です。対象のハードウェア構成・OS・処理内容・データ／ワークロードでいくらでも結果が変わってしまいます。

例えば下記サイトでは、コンパイラやCPUの定期的なベンチマーク性能比較を行っていますので、ご参考にしてください。

- [GCC 8 vs. LLVM Clang 6 Performance At End Of Year 2017](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=gcc-clang-eoy2017)

Comment: おまけ：どちらのコンパイラを選ぶべきか迷っているのであれば、環境構築でトラブルが少ない方を選べばよいと思います。お勧めは2つ以上のコンパイラをサポートしておくことです。片方のコンパイラでは見つけられないソースコードの問題を、他コンパイラが指摘するかもしれません。ただまぁ、ライブラリ開発でもない限りは趣味の問題かもしれません。